# How to detect all the mso-bookmarks in a html file?

Tags: javascript, html

MS Word uses these html parts to define an anchor:

```
<span style='mso-bookmark:<SomeName>'></span>
```

In javascript I want to have a collection of those items and edit them.
I can get all the span elements with:

```
var msWordAnchors=document.getElementsByTagName("span");
```

But I cannot find a way to see if the style contains an mso-bookmark.
I tried something like:

```
element.style.indexOf('mso-bookmark') >= 0
```

but style is not a string.

I tried

```
element.style.toString()
```

but that gives me the object name, not the content. Also element.style.mso-bookmark
does not work. I am a little lost now. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a valid style declaration, so you can't get the style, but you can get the attributes value

```
element.getAttribute('style').indexOf('mso-bookmark') != -1
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/e989C/)

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to use it at this moment! :-)

Comment: It works, and I now also know the difference between valid style declaration and non valid style declaration. Thanks for the lesson.